# mono AOT on Windows exe gives me an DLL

Tags: windows, mono, aot

I'm on Windows and I'm trying ahead of time compilation on `Main.exe` that's been compiled with the Mono C# compiler `gmcs` (also tried `mcs`).

```
>mono --aot Main.exe
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\test\Main.exe 
Code: 21   Info: 4 Ex Info: 8 Class Info: 30 PLT: 2 GOT 
Info: 6 GOT Info Offsets: 8 GOT: 12 
Executing the native assembler: as C:\DOCUME~1\MigueldeIcaza\LOCALS~1\Temp\mono_aot_D2 ID2U -o C:\DOCUME~1\MigueldeIcaza\LOCALS~1\Temp\mono_aot_D2ID2U.o 
Executing the native linker: gcc -shared --dll -mno-cygwin -o C:\test\Main.exe.dll C:\DOCUME~1\MigueldeIcaza\LOCALS~1\Temp\mono_aot_D2ID2U.o 
Compiled 2 out of 2 methods (100%) Methods without GOT slots: 2 (100%) 
Direct calls: 0 (100%) JIT time: 0 ms, Generation time: 0 ms, 
Assembly+Link time: 319 ms. GOT slot distribution:
image: 1
```

but that produces a `Main.exe.dll` and I want an **executable**.
Is that possible?

**Update:**

I intercepted the AOT/build process by write protecting `Main.exe.dll` and now I have a `mono_aot_FZKP2U.o` but still no luck:

```
>gcc -o Main2.exe mono_aot_FZKP2U.o
/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0x104): 
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

**Update 2009-10-30:**

After reading Jb Evains answer I once again tried to runt the Main.exe.dll with mono with no success.

```
C:\test>mono Main.exe.dll
Mono-INFO: Assembly Loader probing location: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\mono\1.
0\mscorlib.dll'.
Mono-INFO: Image addref mscorlib 003E5F48 -> C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\mono\1.0
\mscorlib.dll 00B42BC0: 2

Mono-INFO: AOT failed to load AOT module C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\mono\1.0\msc
orlib.dll.dll: The system cannot find the file specified.


Mono-INFO: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.
3\lib\mono\1.0\mscorlib.dll'.
Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\mono\1.0\msco
rlib.dll.config'.
Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\..\etc\mono\a
ssemblies\mscorlib\mscorlib.config'.
Mono-INFO: Assembly mscorlib 003E5F48 added to domain Main.exe.dll, ref_count=1

Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\..\etc\mono\c
onfig'.
Mono-INFO: Assembly Loader probing location: 'Main.exe.dll'.
Cannot open assembly 'Main.exe.dll': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
Mono-INFO: Unloading domain Main.exe.dll 00B04EA0, assembly mscorlib 003E5F48, r
efcount=1

Mono-INFO: Unloading assembly mscorlib [003E5F48].
Mono-INFO: Unloading image C:\PROGRA~1\MONO-2~1.3\lib\mono\1.0\mscorlib.dll [00B
42BC0].
```

Comment: Your problem lies in the gcc call, which compiles it explicitly to a library...maybe this is a wanted behavior?

Comment: Yes but the mono_aot_D2ID2U.o is deleted in the process so I get no chance to run gcc myself.

Comment: Also the documentation hints that it works under *nix. http://mono-project.com/AOT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mono AOT compilation process doesn't create an executable. It indeed creates a library. Mono automatically picks up the AOTed code if possible, you just have to run mono Main.exe like you would normally do. You can check by specifying the environment variable `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` if Mono picks up the native code.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of the MONO_LOG_LEVEL.

Comment: I can't make the dll run either. See my update to the question.

Comment: Well, you can't «run» a dll. As I said, run `mono Main.exe`, and mono will load Main.exe.dll for you.

Comment: "(Main.exe:3248): Mono-DEBUG: AOT FOUND AOT compiled code for test.MainClass:Main" - thanks!